# Can't get modiified array out of 'for' statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, service-worker

I'm trying to add items from a modified list of thumbs to a service worker storage cache by JSON import.

Everything's working as far as generating a correctly-formatted and complete array of thumbs to cache --`console.log(cacheArray)`inside the `for` statement -- but I can't seem to get a final array out of the function --`console.log('updateCache: ' + cacheArray)`returns a blank:

```
    fetch('alldates.txt').then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(string) {
        var alldatesobj = JSON.parse(string);
        var cacheThumb;
        var thumbslist = Object.values(alldatesobj);
        var cacheArray = new Array();
        function updateCache(cacheArray) {
            for(i = 1; i <= thumbslist.length; i++) {
                cacheThumb = thumbslist[i].replace('100315', '100315/thumbs');
                cacheArray.push(cacheThumb);
                //console.log(cacheArray.slice(-1)[0]);
                //console.log(cacheArray);
                //^^^ array is correctly formed!!!
            }
            return cacheArray;
        }
        updateCache(console.log('updateCache: ' + cacheArray));
    });
```

Comment: Your code calls `updateCache()`, which returns an array, but you don't do anything with the returned value.

Comment: ... and `console.log()` always returns `undefined`, so you're not passing an array into the function.

Comment: `updateCache(console.log('updateCache: ' + cacheArray));` makes no sense. I am guessing you meant:  `console.log('updateCache: ' + updateCache());`

Comment: I can only repeat that `console.log(cacheArray)` works as expected inside the `for` statement, but the updated cacheArray variable is not accessible outside (which is to say, I can't work out the syntax for it) -- I'm using the console to test for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regrettably, I was unable to parse the replies: even though they were pointing in the general direction, I lack the underlying knowledge.

Someone else provided the solution:

```
fetch('alldates.txt').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(string) {
    var alldatesobj = JSON.parse(string);
    var cacheArray = Object.values(alldatesobj).map(function(item){
        return item.replace(/100315/,'$&/thumbs');
    });
    console.log('cacheArray: ' + cacheArray);
});
```